# C# - clarifying 'where T:new()'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How should the following line be understood?

```
public T Execute<t>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
```

It is part of the code below.

```
public T Execute<t>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    // Used on every request
    request.AddParameter("country", "gb", ParameterType.UrlSegment);

    var response = client.Execute<t>(request);
    return response.Data;
}
```

And also this one:

> public class RssItems : List{}

Comment: [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: you didnt use the constraint here at all

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx

Comment: @RoyiNamir It may be the case that `client.Execute<T>(RestRequest)` has this constraint, so the caller has to also pass the constraint on (or validate it at runtime, and do the right thing)

Comment: he wrote <t> and not <T>

Comment: Yeah that's wrong too, but I don't think that's the focus of his question.  He wasn't asking "why doesn't this work?" just what the type constraint signified.

Answer (score 4):

When you're dealing with generics, type constraints define ways you can use the generics.  The

```
where T : new()
```

means it has a parameterless constructor, allowing you to use the code:

```
var something = new T();
```

in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The type constraint means that `T` must have a parameter less constructor. See MSDN documentation on [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**UPDATE**
The line `public class RssItems : List {}` means that `RssItems` inherits from `List`. See [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Xharze, are you able to tell me what this means? public class RssItems : List<item>{}

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying that the `T` (generic type) must have a parameterless `ctr`.

Comment: It only specifies that `T` must have a parameterless constructor.  It does not mean it must be a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

The method will return an object of Type T which was defined when the class was created with:

```
var x = new SomeClass<T>();
```

the part: T: new() means the type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used in conjunction with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last. You can check this on the MSDN page 'Constraints on Type Parameters'